# JavaScript Change Element Type

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a button and i want when i clicked on it add an input and after press enter input be button or something else.

---

```
<button>add tag</button>
<input type="text" name="" placeholder="tag">
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('button').click(function () {
            $("button").before("input");
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    $("body").before("input");
  });
  $("input").keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13)
      $(this).attr("type", "button");
    $(this).val('button')
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>add tag</button>
<input type="text" name="" placeholder="tag"><button>add tag</button>
<input type="text" name="" placeholder="tag"><button>add tag</button>
<input type="text" name="" placeholder="tag"><button>add tag</button>
<input type="text" name="" placeholder="tag"><button>add tag</button>
<input type="text" name="" placeholder="tag"><button>add tag</button>
<input type="text" name="" placeholder="tag">
```

Comment: thanks.how i can repeat these codes for all time?this code happen just for one time.

Comment: Check the edits. It will work with any button or input

Comment: your answer for one of my question is correct but i want when i clicked on add tag open an input and  then save it as button.With all due respect,do you understand my question?

Comment: What does **open an input and save it as a button** means?I mean as far as I know we can focus on an input element or create an input element. What is opening it? In place of the input text do you need an input element??